# what happens if box has a run schedule and its starting conditions are not met?

Tags: autosys

I have a box which has its own start time and starting conditions on other boxes. Say the box has a start time of 5:30 and has condition like s(a, 30)&s(b, 22)&s(c)

What will happen at 5:30 if all the conditions are not met?

Will the box trigger ever, when the conditions are met even after 5:30?

Answer (score 1):

Box will stay INACTIVE until ALL the conditions (no matter date or starting) become true.

So at 5:30 it will be still INACTIVE if any of conditions is not met.

And yes, box will trigger when the conditions are met even after 5:30.

Comment: Thank you.So this box B is now say INACTIVE. IF there is other job A having s(B), will A trigger? I Suppose yes.

Comment: Yes, it will be triggered immediately in such case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the jobs A and B have look back times set on them (that's the part after the name of the job and the comma), this will alter the behavior as outlined by the previous answer.

At 5:30a the box will kick off only if job A has reached success state within the previous 30 minutes and job B has reached success within the last 22 minutes. C must also be in success but with no specific look back interval.

If 5:30a comes around and job A went into success at 4:45a (more than 30 mins earlier) the box will not kick off. Same with job B at 22 minutes.  If 5:30a comes around and job A and C are in success with job B still running (or in success from 22+ minutes earlier) the box will not kick off. If 6:01a comes around and job B goes into success the box will not run because the last success of A was 30+ minutes prior.

I hope this makes sense. I should add that I usually recommend against using a specific lookback time in favor of using a 0 lookback. This translates roughly as 'since the last time that I was used to kick you off'... But that being said, there are definitely cases where a specific lookback is appropriate. Without more information it's hard to determine if that is true in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Box will stay INACTIVE until ALL off the conditions met.

So at 5:30 it will be still INACTIVE if any of conditions is not met.

And yes, box will trigger when the conditions are met even after 5:30.

And all job in Box will be in INACTIVE state, if job is independent to box and it met all conditions then this job be in running state.